IFC Visibility Issue: APS Viewer vs ACC Viewer Behavior with Viewer.ShowAll()
We are currently working with the APS Viewer and have encountered an issue related to element visibility when working with IFC files.
Usually, IFC element such as IFC Spaces and IFC Openings, are hidden by default in most viewers. When resetting the model's visibility, the expected behavior is for these originally hidden elements to remain hidden.
However, in the APS Viewer, when we reset visibility using
viewer.showAll(),

these originally hidden elements become visible again. Interestingly, we observed the same behavior on the default APS Viewer (viewer.autodesk.com).
In contrast, the ACC Viewer behaves as expected—when using the "Show All Objects" option via the right-click menu, originally hidden elements remain hidden.
Upon investigation, we noticed that both ACC Viewer and APS Viewer use the same
viewer.showAll() 

API. This suggests that the ACC Viewer must have an additional mechanism or implementation to handle originally hidden elements effectively.
ACC Viewer
viewer.autodesk
We would greatly appreciate any insights or details regarding the implementation differences or specific APIs used in the ACC Viewer to achieve this behavior.
Looking forward to your guidance.
